# Mobile WiFi Encryptio

Tags: wi-fi, password, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm trying to retrieve saved wifi passwords on my Note 3 mobile phone (rooted) but the file has the passwords encrypted. Anyway to decrypt it and stop my phone from encrypting it.

The encryption is not hex like below

4e0b011c8c40445fdafced88ab703ab5

Is it MD5?